# Booting the already installed Ubuntu 14 from the VirtualBox installed in Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, windows, virtualbox

I was wondering if there is any way to start ubuntu System in VirtualBox from Windows 7 which is already installed on harddisk

Comment: Why do you want that, it is bit risky one. Anyway please take a look at this link... http://chaits.accosted.net/?p=54. It provides steps for the same.

Comment: I am not 100 % sure, i just wanted to know if it is possible...Actually i want to delete Ubuntu and that caused me a lot of problems until now and i am still trying to figure out how to solve this ...But thanks for the great link!